# Writing a partnership contract for a website

Tags: web-development, contract

My boss has offered me a 25% share, in exchange on more input from my side, of a website ( a crawling engine in php and a front end using ajax ) I developed for him. What are the things I should consider in writing the contract so that my share is future proof?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about legal advice and contract law.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As programmers, we are not very good at legal things. Here are the things you should consider in **writing the contract**:

- **Don't write the contract**. Your lawyer should do it. Or he will contribute to the contract your boss's lawyer will write.
- Clearly **define your work** in the contract so your boss can't extract the value from the association you just created.
- Define what **more input** means with required limit in amount or work and time. You must ensure that you agree with the amount of work you will provide for the 25%.
- Clearly define in the contract what happens in case of any of **you wants to end collaboration**.

You may be interested in my answer on the question [Are we about to be shafted by a corporate shark](http://www.brightjourney.com/q/shafted-corporate-shark) that address the problem of partnership.

Other answers may provide you with valuable complementary information.